# Refactoring JS function and Removing conditional out of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

As title explains im trying to understand the best way to refactor my function and also remove my if statement from the loop? Any guidance would be appreciated. As I have an idea that me else condition is useless.

```
function quantitySum(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
    if (array[0].length > 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(array[0][i].f0_);
    } else {
      sum === 0;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: `sum === 0` doesn't do anything. It's a comparison, not an assignment, but you're not doing anything with the comparison result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `if/else` condition at all as if there are no items in `array[0]`, there will be no iteration.

```
    function quantitySum(array) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
         sum += parseFloat(array[0][i].f0_);
      }
      return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Array reduce function

```
function sum = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator += parseFloat(current.f0_)) || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit extreme, but you could go with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) inside an ES6 arrow function and dramatically reduce the code

```js
const quantitySum = array => array[0]?.reduce((b,a) => b+parseFloat(a.f0_),0) ?? 0;

let n = [[{f0_:5}, {f0_:6}]]
let o = []
console.log(quantitySum(n))
console.log(quantitySum(o))
```